# How to find where a .js library is loaded ("imported")

Tags: javascript

I've got a .js file  (main.js) that uses SetCookie() from **cookies.js**

But I can't see where *cookies.js* is *ever* loaded or "imported". It's not listed in the main.js, it's not listed in the page. It's not listed in any of the Included .js files.

How could I find where it's loaded?

Comment: do you use any js lib, in the main.js?

Comment: @Clay Hello, could you check if [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44653361/4927984) helped you?

Comment: @Mistalis, I'm not looking for the where the .js file is *stored*, but, rather, where it is "called" or "imported" (i.e. where in the .js code it asks to load that .js file)

Answer (score 1):

With a browser, you can see the path of resources you loaded on your page.

From Firefox:

- Press F12 to open the console
- Select the Debugger tab
- Go to your website, you will see all the JS loaded, with path.

Screenshot for Stack Overflow:

[image]

Depending of the domain/path of the file, you may know if it is an external (or not) library, and from where it comes from.